# C++: Adding methods to a polymorphic class hierarchy without violating SRP?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, single-responsibility-principle

I have a design issue that I constantly keep encountering.

For the sake of illustration, let's assume that I have a polymorphic class hierarchy

```
class A { public: virtual ~A() {} ... };
class B: public A { ... };
class C: public B { ... };
class D: public A { ... };
...
```

I want to be able to print instances of these classes in a polymorphic way, i.e. each class has its own way of printing itself. The obvious way of achieving this would be to add

```
virtual void print(OutputStream &os) = 0;
```

into the base class and override this method in every subclass. However, if the original responsibility of the classes is not related to printing, this will add another responsibility to them, thus violating [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

My question is: what is a proper way of achieving the desired behavior without violating SRP?

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2352533/2580955), a solution based on the [Visitor design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_design_pattern) is proposed. However, then I would need to create a class which has to know about every subclass of `A`. I would like to be able to add and remove subclasses without a need to always modify the visitor.

Is there some other, SRP-preserving way than the two ways described above?

Comment: What does your print() method do? Does its output contain any information about internals of the class? In that case, I would put its definition into the class, because the only other option is to break encapsulation and that is even less agile. All other solutions I am aware of would be related to implementing dynamic dispatch for function arguments in C++ and that can be ugly.

Comment: @Markus Mayr: Let's assume that the emitted information can be obtained from the public interface of every subclass, but not necessarily by using only the base class interface. Otherwise, as you have already mentioned, ecapsulation would need to be broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an *acyclic visitor* pattern that eliminates the need to know about every subclass. It relies on `dynamic_cast`, but may be what you need.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this pattern! This may be what I need, although the answer of n.m. also makes sense. But your answer is applicable also to other cases, where there is a clear violation.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with a class printing itself. It does not violate SRP because printing does not constitute a responsibility.

Remember that responsibility is defined as a reason to change. You don't change a class because your requirements for printing change. The class should only send name-value pairs to the entity responsible for printing, called *the formatter*. This procedure of sending name-value pairs never ever changes by itself. Any changes in it are only prompted by other changes, unrelated to printing (when you e.g. add a field, you also add its representation to the printing procedure).

The formatter should know nothing about the classes it prints, but simply present the name-value pairs according to some set of requirements. The formatter changes when the printing requirements change. Therefore printing would be the sole responsibility of the formatter.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to go for some sort of visitor of double dispatch solution in order to do this. The double dispatch approach is a bit more lightweight, so how about something like this:

In A:

```
class Processor
{
public:
  virtual void Process(const A &a)const {}
  virtual void Process(const B &b)const {}
  virtual void Process(const C &c)const {}
  virtual void Process(const D &d)const {}
  virtual void Process(const E &e)const {}
};
```

In A:

```
class A
{
public:
  virtual void Process(const Processor &processor) 
  {
    processor.Process(*this);
  }
};
```

Then, in each derived class override `Process` with an identical definition:

```
virtual void Process(const Processor &processor) 
{
  processor.Process(*this);
}
```

This will ensure that the correct overload in `Process` is called.

Now, create a stream processor:

```
class StreamProcessor : public Processor
{
private:
 OutputStream &m_OS;

public:
  StreamProcessor(OutputStream &os) : m_OS(os)
  {
  }

  virtual void Processor(const A &a)const
  {
   m_os << "got a A";
  }

  virtual void Processor(const B &b)const
  {
   m_os << "got a B";
  }

  virtual void Processor(const C &c)const
  {
   m_os << "got a C";
  }

  // etc
};
```

And then:

```
 OutputStream &operator<<(OutputStream &os, A &a)
 {
   PrintProcessor(os);
   a.Process(PrintProcessor);
   return os;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, as I have suggested in the question, I would like to be able to add and remove subclasses without a need to always modify the visitor (`Processor` in your example).

Comment: Fair enough, but you're going to have to modify _something_ as you add or remove classes. In languages like Java of C# you could use relfection, but that's not an option to you in C++.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide an interface for printing responsibility and keep common responsibilities under your class hierarchy. Example:

```
class Printer { public: virtual void print(OutputStream &os) = 0; }
class A { public: virtual ~A() {} ... };
class B: public A, public Printer { ... }; // this needs print function, use interface.
class C: public B { ... };
class D: public A { ... };
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I want to be able to print any subclass of `A`, not just `B` and its subclasses. This may be solved by inheriting from `Printer` in `A`. However, I'm still wondering whether this approach violates SRP or not.

Comment: I am not sure what is the problem if you want to be able to print all classes of A. If printing is needed on subclasses of A, then you they should have it. Evaluating if such need is necessary for those classes or not up to you (impossible for us to evaluate with limited info) but from what I understand you want to print subclasses of A and implementing print function is not violation of SRP if inherited classes need it.